# How call function with callback parameter?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, async-await, asynccallback

I have this function with callback parameter `Action<string> callback`:

```
 public void sync(Action<string> callback)
        {

            var client = new RestClient(RestfulPaths.BASE_URL);
            var request = new RestRequest(RestfulPaths.SYNC_CHECK, Method.GET);
            var json = client.Execute(request);

            client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
            {
                callback(response.Content);
            });

        }
```

I tried to call this function in another part of application:

```
ServerSync = manager.sync({
   // Get data here
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Action` indicates that it is a delegate that has no return value.  The type parameter `string` indicates that the action will take a single parameter of type string.  So to use it, you have to pass a delegate that accepts a string parameter.  A simple way to do this is:

```
manager.sync((responseContent)=>{
    Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
});
```

Comment: `Action indicates that it is a delegate that has no return value.`. What does it mean? Now it returns value is not?

Comment: It doesn't return a value.  In the example you provided, the delegate method is called with the `response.Content` that is retrieved from the rest call

Comment: So, inside delegate I can get response result?

Comment: Yes, I updated the code to indicate that the variable passed to the delegate is the value that contains the content.

Comment: So, this delegate does not have name, is as anonymous?

Comment: Yes, this would be considered anonymous.  You could also define a `void` function that accepts a string and pass that in as the delegate.

Comment: Can you explain me case when I need to bind progressbar to async request, so I need to return the second parameter in callback?